# Installing gcc on a PC and got several errors

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I've tried installing the gcc by my self. When i tried to run my C code using Visual Studio, several errors  are found. Any solution for my problem?

i have installed MinGW and followed the instructions on youtube

what i expect in the terminal is Hello World, what i got is this error about access denied 
// I'm using Win 10
//The Youtube Video : https://youtu.be/mWzOu-_VNAk

---

PS

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file Untitled-1.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\farhandika\projects\projects\projects\helloworld>
```

Comment: By "PC" do you mean "Windows"? If so, what version?

Comment: Why MinGW and not Visual Studio Express if you want to write C code? Building C code is often non-trivial, so you'll either need to compose a `Makefile` or CMake equivalent, if not use an IDE like Visual Studio Express that can help you through the process of building a viable executable.

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please take the [tour], learn [ask], and provide a [example]. In your case provide all that is necessary to repeat what you did. Especially **which** YouTube video? Please [edit] your question with additional information, don't hide it in comments.

Comment: i'm using win 10.
The 1st run was a success

Comment: Welcome to SO. I cannot find "this error about access denied". The message you show indicates "file not found" which is not the same.

Comment: i think i posted the wrong line

Comment: OK. That's a totally different story. In most cases your executable is already running and hence the file cannot be overwritten.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied - cannot open outputfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855571/permission-denied-cannot-open-outputfile)

Comment: Searching for "[c] mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file" produces multiple results that are very near to your problem.